Android resource linking failed with AAPT2: missing mipmap/ic_launcher and themes (NormalTheme and LaunchTheme)
I'm working on a Flutter application and running into an issue when trying to build in release mode on a Linux server via SSH. The processReleaseResources task fails with the following errors:
Android resource linking failed
/home/twtransport/public_html/userapp.transwift-transport.fr/android/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:36: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.transwift.app:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
/home/twtransport/public_html/userapp.transwift-transport.fr/android/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:47: error: resource style/NormalTheme (aka com.transwift.app:style/NormalTheme) not found.
/home/twtransport/public_html/userapp.transwift-transport.fr/android/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:54: error: resource style/LaunchTheme (aka com.transwift.app:style/LaunchTheme) not found.


It seems that the app can't locate some key resources, like the ic_launcher icon and the NormalTheme and LaunchTheme styles. I’ve checked the android/app/src/main/res directory, and the mipmap-* folders do contain the necessary icons, but this doesn’t resolve the issue. The styles are also defined in styles.xml, but the build errors persist.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Verified that resources are present in the correct folders (mipmap-* for the icon and styles.xml for themes).
Ran ./gradlew clean followed by ./gradlew assembleRelease, but no success.
Added simplified theme definitions directly in styles.xml as a test.
